# Error in Java with file reading

Tags: java

So there is the code:

```
public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException{
    new Main().run();
  }
  PrintWriter pw;
  Scanner sc;
  public void run() throws IOException{
    sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    int a=sc.nextInt();
    pw = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));
    pw.print(a*a);
    pw.close();
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: input.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Main.run(Main.java:14)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Like i understand it can't find file named input.txt, BUT! I have that file in same directory where Main class is, what can be the promblem then?
p.s Tried on cmd and eclipse, both give same error.

Comment: Hint: see what `file.getAbsolutePath()` returns.

Comment: I tried (new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\output.txt"), didn't work, did i something wrong?

Comment: @XsergeiX Just saying `new File("output.txt");` already does that.

Comment: well, now i figured out that it doesn't work only in eclipse, maybe i need to change permissions or something like so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to specify the PATH to your file, one thing you can do is test for existence and readability with [`File.canRead()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead%28%29) like

```
File file = new File("input.txt");
if (!file.canRead()) {
    System.err.println(file.getCanonicalPath() + ": cannot be read");
    return;   
}
```

An example using a PATH might be (for Windows) -

```
File file = new File("c:/mydir/input.txt");
```

Comment: Move the file `input.txt` to that PATH. That is where it is trying to read it. Or use the last sentence to explicitly point out a full (or relative `../input.txt`) path.

Answer (score 4):

it is not relative to your Main class, it is relative from where you launch this Java program (i.e. current work directory)

it is relative to

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

Comment: well, lets check it out

Comment: Saw this too late. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))` to see where Java is looking for the file by default. This is most likely your project folder. This is were you have to put the file if you don't want to specify an absolute path.